# Stuck in initramfs after logical volume resize volume group not found

Tags: ubuntu, initramfs, rootfs

Hoping someone can help me recover my ubuntu server instance. Ran out of space on a VM and decided to extend the virtual disk.

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 37.00 GiB (9472 extents) to <74.00 GiB (18943 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
```

This I noticed worked but only to 75GB so realised I still needed to increase the partiiton size which I did like below:

```
sudo growpart /dev/xvda 3
CHANGED: partition=3 start=2101248 old: size=155183104 end=157284352 new: size=417329119 end=419430367
```

I then thought I could go back and run the original command again as lsblk returned below which looked good to me:

```
lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2246
loop1                       7:1    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2253
loop2                       7:2    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1242
loop3                       7:3    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1270
loop4                       7:4    0 67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21803
loop5                       7:5    0 67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
loop6                       7:6    0 42.2M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14066
loop7                       7:7    0 43.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14295
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
xvda                      202:0    0  200G  0 disk
├─xvda1                   202:1    0    1M  0 part
├─xvda2                   202:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─xvda3                   202:3    0  199G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   74G  0 lvm  /
xvdb                      202:16   0  5.4T  0 disk
└─xvdb1                   202:17   0  5.4T  0 part /mnt/media
```

So executed `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` again however ran into this error:

```
user@server:~$ sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
  Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
```

I gave up in the end as all was working and I had increased my space to get by enough for a while but thought I would come back later...I didn't before a reboot and now i'm stuck in initramfs getting errors like this on boot similar to the ones I had experienced when tryning to extend the volume:

```
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
...
    ALERT!  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

**Other notes**

Looking back over what I did i'm worried this may have been an issue:

```
sudo fdisk -u /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The old ext4 signature will be removed by a write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xaae0d62a.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 73.102 GiB, 79452700672 bytes, 155181056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xaae0d62a

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.
```

Just kind of thought that warning above meant something needed updated so just haphazardly did that to both that disk and the one below:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/xvda3

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The old LVM2_member signature will be removed by a write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xfc8b2324.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/xvda3: 73.102 GiB, 79453749248 bytes, 155183104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfc8b2324

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.
```

And here I am stuck in this initramfs shell hoping someone can help men fix this without rebuilding the whole thing... I may have missed some issues and bits but tried to explain as well as i possibly can what may have gone wrong just hoping it may be something simple to undo?